# Missing properties in window when using a content script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

My addon is injecting some content scripts into various websites. After trying to bind `onbeforeunload` or calling `window.location.reload` I realized that the window object misses some properties.

Is there a way to binding certain events (`onbeforeunload`, `onunload`, etc) while injecting code via `page-mod` module?

I've created a test add-on, showing that these properties are missing: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1037497/latest/

Solutions on how to use them anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You add an event listener using `addEventListener()` method, like this:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event)
{
  ...
}, false);
```

Long answer: For security reasons your content script isn't communicating with the DOM objects directly, e.g. it cannot see any script-added properties. The [technical details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper) also list some limitations:

> Assigning to or reading an `on*` property on an `XPCNativeWrapper` of a
>   DOM node or Window object will throw an exception. (Use
>   `addEventListener` instead, and use `event.preventDefault();` in your
>   handler if you used `return false;` before.)

In a content script you probably don't want to replace the web page's event handlers anyway, rather add your own - that's what `addEventListener()` is doing.

[Additional reading](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/dev-guide/addon-development/content-scripts/access.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question again! Well, my problem had a different source. A third party library replaced addEventListener without me noticing it. After removing the library my existing script started working like a charm.